# merging old branch created in svn using git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge

We had an old svn repository that was migrated to git. Before migration we had created a branches in svn that were also migrated. The problem is that when we checkout the old svn branch the files are located under /trunk-folder and our master branch has the files in repository root folder. For example /trunk/subfolder/source.cs and /subfolder/source.cs. I tried moving files in then svn branch to root folder but when I try merge to master-branch I get bunch of "both-added" conflicts even when the files in both branches are identical. Is there any way to merge these branches without manually solving each conflict ?

Comment: are line endings same in those identical files?

Comment: They might not be. Is there way to mass change line endings in all files?

Comment: @Jargo have you solved the problem yet?

Comment: @Marina I ended up manually checking each conflict with mergetool. It got the job done but it really didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To merge the `old_branch` into `master` and resolve the merge conflicts automatically, you can use `-X` options for `git merge` command.

- `git merge old_branch -X ours` will resolve the merge conflicts automatically by keeping the version on `master` branch.
- `git merge old_branch -X theirs` will  resolve the merge conflicts automatically by keeping the version on the `old_branch`.